# jQuery show and hide not working as expected

Tags: jquery, hide, show

Please check example http://jsfiddle.net/FuFHe/7/

When I click on button Show Data loader div should be displayed and after couple of seconds hidden. In console log you can clearly see that display property of qloader div get set to block and none, but nothing happens, qloader div never gets displayed.

What is wrong?

Comment: you should use `on()` method like this `$(documen).on( "click",'.btn', function( event ){ ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a good way of sleeping. It eats up the CPU, and you can't even rely on it taking the full 3 seconds on a fast machine. Instead [use setTimeout()](http://jsfiddle.net/FuFHe/8/):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();     
    console.log("qloader display = " + $("#loading").css("display")); 
}, 3000);
```

That will allow the browser and your website to continue operating while you are waiting for the time to pass.

Comment: Guys and girls, I just want to simulate calling of CPU consuming function, like getData which should do ajax call for data. It is IRRELEVANT. what is RELEVANT is that loading div is not displayed even so its display property is SET and READs 'block'.

Comment: @sasha No, it's not irrelevant. The whole reason why you're not seeing your div is because you are blocking the browser from doing its work. The browser doesn't get a chance to paint it before hiding it again. It will not redraw anything until your code returns.

Comment: So, you are saying onclick is blocking event and browser won't redraw until event code is executed?

Comment: It depends on the browser, but in general, yes. Chrome blocks, while Opera seems to redraw.

Comment: So if I want to put 100% width and height div with z-index:10 and put a spinner animated gif centered in that div, what would be the best way to trigger show and hide on button click and not to block gif animation? It seems I will have to work that out by using some kind of semaphores and setInterval? Or maybe generate and catch some kind of custom events? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you are not doing heavy computations, but just waiting for data from the server (aka ajax) or something, then the approach in my and the other answers will be all you need. Just let the hiding function be triggered by the ajax callback instead of a timer.

Comment: Basically all answers were informative and could lead to soultion, I choose this one because of useful comments we made. Thank you all. For last, here is what I wanted to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/FuFHe/20/

Comment: @sasha Note though, that you don't need to wrap the `getData()` call in `setTimeout`, because `$.ajax` already works asynchronously by default (i.e. it returns immediately without waiting for the response from the server). Also, when using setTimeout, you want to pass the _function_ to setTimeout, not the _return value_ of the function, so it should be `setTimeout(getData,30)` instead of `setTimeout(getData(),30)` :)

Answer (score 2):

why using `sleep` use `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $("#loading").hide();},3000);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FuFHe/16/)

Comment: I use sleep to simulate passage of time, like I get when in stead of sleep I call getData() (ajax call to get data). I want to avoid using setTimeout if possible. What is actually wrong with calling show, getData(), hide? Why is div not displayed? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a `sleep()` function right when the `show()` function is finished.
Checkout the fiddle. It should work now. **[JSFIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/FuFHe/9/)**

But as mentioned by @rahul, you should use `setTimeout()` function.

```
$("#loading").show(function(){
    sleep(3000);
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Comment: I checked this and it works on code I provided. However, if you put 100% width and height div with z-index:10 and put a spinner animated gif centered in that div, loading div get's visible but animation is halted. Is there any way to show loading div with animated spinner as onclick event?

Comment: if you will make a demo in jsfiddle or jsbin, we could work that out

Comment: Ok, in short while I will do just that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTimeout

```
$('.btn').on( "click" , function( event ){
 $("#loading").show(); 
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("#loading").hide();
    }, 3000);

});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FuFHe/14/)

Comment: I put sleep on purpose, to simulate passage of time, like for getData function which makes ajax calls for data and that I use after calling show. What is stopping div from being displayed in code I used?